# Putting text of PlantUML gantt chart deliverable/milestone left of diamond?

Tags: layout, gantt-chart, plantuml, milestone

When looking at:

```
@startgantt
[Prototype design] lasts 1 weeks
then [Prototype completed]  lasts 4 days
[End Prototype completed] happens at [Prototype completed]'s end
then [Test prototype] lasts 5 days
[End Test prototype] happens at [Test prototype]'s end

[Prototype completed] is deleted
[End Prototype completed] is deleted
@endgantt
```

which yields:

[image]

Is it possible to put the text: `End Test prototype` left of the last diamond deliverable/milestone?

That would make the Gantt chart a bit less wide, which in some cases can be convenient for readability. I did not find any examples of text left of a deliverable in [the examples](https://plantuml.com/gantt-diagram).

Comment: I don't think it can be done, but it seems like a reasonable request for a feature. You could ask for it on https://forum.plantuml.net/